# What is the meaning of "ever the academic?"

Tags: phrases

I found this phrase in a story I intended to translate. I've searched it on Google but there's nothing about this phrase. Does it really have a meaning?

Comment: It simply means that that characteristic of the person had an effect on how he reacted in a given situation.  Eg, an academic will analyze, a detective will search for clues, a carpenter will study the construction of things.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a fixed phrase but an instance of a standard construction, *ever the NOUN*. *Ever* here has the sense *always*. Phrases of this usually occur in apposition to the subject of a clause and characterize the subject's action as typical of his identity as a *NOUN*:

> Ever the academic, John is reluctant to give off-the-cuff opinions: he prefers to research a subject thoroughly.

These phrases are often employed to suggest that the subject's action is not entirely appropriate to the situation.

> While Kevin and Amy hurried to clean the victim's wounds, John, ever the academic, became absorbed in the contents of his bookshelves.